# Member Group preferences resetting

Tags: members, channel-preferences

I have a peculiar problem with a recent EE 2.5.5 site we launched. I've setup a member group for client access with appropriate channels assigned to them. The problem is that somehow their channel access keeps resetting resulting in no access to channels. I've reset their group preferences many times be it keeps getting reset back to none.

Could this be happening on the client end? The group preference doesn't allow them access to the Member area so I kinda doubt it. I rarely access this section of EE so I doubt it's something I'm doing.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOU FOUND A BUG! I'm guessing you have more than one member group? I thought it had been fixed in 2.5.5... may not? there's a known solution over at: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/18234

Comment: That solution wouldn't be applicable any more as the chunk of code it refers to has been relocated, plus that fix has already been applied to the core anyway. So if it is a bug it's a likely a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. We do have several member groups. And the code was different now. I'll try a "clean" install and see if that makes a difference. I have been using DevDemon's Updater to run the upgrades.